# Multithreaded Observer Pattern Method and Event Order

Tags: multithreading, observer-pattern

I have a thread-safe subject class. Any observer of the subject receives subjects events in the order that changes happend at the subject.

When an observer called a method of the subject, the value returned from the method shows the current state of the subject. But that value did not come from the event of the subject. Because of that there may be other events that happend before this method call and not yet notified to the observer at that moment. So if onserver uses the value it received from method call to update itself, it may get updated on wrong order.

My question is, in observer pattern do subjects methods can have return values? Or one who calls any method of the subject should get the result of the method from events?